# Populate form fields from database using Codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

i am trying to populate two form fields from data that is retrieved from a database, in order for the user to update them. The table is called `records` and it is quite simple:

Record_ID
title
content

My model:

```
function get_data()
{
    $r = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $query = $this->db->get_where('records', array('Record_ID' => $r));
    return $query->result();
}
```

My controller:

```
function set_values()
{
    $data = $this->entries_model->get_data();
    $this->load->view('update_view', $data);                       
}
```

and my update record view:

```
<?php

echo form_open('site/update',$data);?>
Title:
<?php echo form_input('title',set_value('title'));?>
Content:
<?php echo form_input('content',set_value('content'));
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');?>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

The problem is that i get the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: views/update_view.php
>
> Line Number: 10

My question is twofold:

1. How do i access this data in my view form and
2. how do i populate the respective fields with it.

I am new to Codeigniter, my questions may look simplistic but any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going on here:

1. $data is an array or object that is [passed to a view](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html). It's ELEMENTS are then available as variables in the view. So, $data['myelement'] = 'somevalue' in the controller would be accessed as $somevalue in the view.
2. If you pass a 2nd parameter to the [form_open()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) method, it is expected to be a key/value pair of attributes for the  tag that will be generated. like, array('class' => 'form_class', 'id' => 'form_id')
3. If you want to set the values of your form inputs, use the view helper function [set_value()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html). In your case, use the controller to set elements in the $data array you'll pass to the view. `$data['form_values'] = array('title' => $title, 'content' => $content);`

Then, in the view:

Comment: Thanks for all the info, it really helped me understand things. But how do i go in the set_value() in the view ? Alredy tried umefarooq's proposed syntax but i get errors i.e.         <?php echo form_input('title',set_value((is_object($mydata)?$mydata->title:'')));?>">
and receive 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 1010
three times in a row.

Comment: Here's an example from one of my apps for how I do it: 
 <?php echo form_input('cluster', set_value('cluster', $envs['cluster']));?>

In this case, the controller set a value $data['envs']...the value set was an array that contained an element 'cluster', like: $data['envs'] = array('name' => $envName, 'cluster' => $clusterName). So, when $data was passed to the view, $envs became a variable of type Array available in the view. set_value() set the value of the form element name=cluster to the value $envs['cluster'].

Make sense?

Comment: Thank you very much jcorry, i found out this solution a few days it's exactly as you say. Thank you again for your time and replies.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a array to your view file. So replace:

```
$data = $this->entries_model->get_data();
```

with:

```
$data['entries_data'] = $this->entries_model->get_data();
```

and on your view file replace:

```
echo form_open('site/update',$data);?>
```

with:

```
echo form_open('site/update',$entries_data);?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , already did that. It appears it can't read the values i put in the setvalue() function.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to pass data in proper way

replace

```
$data = $this->entries_model->get_data();

with:

$data['data'] = $this->entries_model->get_data();
```

for setting value in set_value you need to do the in-line condition check to check either data is an object or not if object then put value other wise just empty

```
<?php echo form_input('title',set_value((is_object($data)?$data->title:'')));?>
```

you have to do the same thing for your all form fields

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i did that and got the following error:

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 1010

Comment: here you are getting multiple records with $query->result(), if you are editing just one record then you need to return $query->row() only one row

Answer (score 0):

Jcory has answered your question but let me add a little to it.

1. In you model instead of `return $query->result();` do this `return $query->row();` this is because using returning a return object requires that you should loop through the resultset in your view
2. Instead of `$data = $this->entries_model->get_data();` do this `$data['entry'] = $this->entries_model->get_data();`
3. In your view do this `<?php echo form_input('title',set_value('title',$entry->title));?>`
   I hope these changes may solve the problem